# Compare dates in array with different timezones in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Hello Everyone consider i stored 4 dates in array 2 of them are from different timezone, now if i want to find out the maxdate and mindate in javascript so can anybody please tell me how can i do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: working code please, theories are not preferred

Comment: Convert date to UTC and compare

Comment: @VinodLouis—Dates **are** UTC.

Comment: @RobG there is a difference between new Date() and .to UTCString() see this https://jsfiddle.net/uxLrn9Lo/ local time and UTC

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Unfortunately, nobody can actually provide a good answer for your question, because you haven't given enough information.  Even Oriel's attempt makes a lot of assumptions about what your input values actually are.  You need to provide *code* showing examples of specific input values.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the help center.

Comment: @VinodLouis—yes, one is a constructor that returns a Date instance, the other is a method that returns a string. ;-) If the date strings are correctly parsed to Dates, they can be compared directly since the time value is UTC.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for comparing dates with diffrent time zone, you need to convert every date to the same time zone(for example your local time zone) , with that all dates will be in same time zone and you will be able to compare them.

for that you have the "Date constructor" ( new Date() )  that take a date and convert it to your local time zone , after you have this all you need to do is do your logic.

heres an example:

```
var date1 = new Date("Wed Mar 25 2015 09:56:24 GMT+0900 (Tokyo Time)"); //new Date will take your time string in tokyo and convert it into your local time zone date and so on...
var date2 = new Date("Wed Mar 25 2015 09:56:24 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)");
var date3 = new Date(Date.now());
var date4 = new Date(Date.now());

var array = [date1 , date2 ,date3 ,date4 ];

var maxDate = new Date(date1);
var minDate = new Date(date1);

for (var i =1 ; i<array.length ; i++){
     if (new Date(array[i]) > maxDate )
        maxDate = new Date(array[i]);

     if (new Date(array[i]) < minDate )
        minDate = new Date(array[i]);
}

alert(minDate.toString() + " " + maxDate.toString());

//Tokyo time is the earliest because is +09:00

//use minDate and maxDate here as you want.
```

Comment: What is the point of `new Date(date1.toUTCString())`? If it is to copy the date, then `new Date(date1)` is sufficient. Code–only answers aren't helpful, you should explain the OP's issue and how to fix it.

Comment: new Date(date1) is not good , because he want to compare dates with different time zone,so toUTCString()  is doing the convert ,but it return string and i want to work with dates for comparing.

Comment: No, it's not doing any conversions at all.  `Date` objects only track a specific moment in time, as milliseconds since the Unix Epoch - which is explicitly in UTC.  The only time `Date` objects work with local time is when you call `toString` either implicitly or explicitly, or if you work with the local-time specific functions like `getHours`, etc.  In your code, you only use local time at the very end, when you implicitly convert to string in the alert.  Everything else in your code is using UTC.

Comment: Keep in mind that `toUTCString` contains `"GMT"` in the output, which when parsed by the `Date` constructor will treat the time as UTC/GMT.  There's no conversions here.  This should not be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: Another way to think about it - the array you made consists of four `Date` objects.  Since `Date` objects can only track specific instants in universal time, you automatically don't have the same situation as the OP asked about.  `Date` objects have no awareness of time zone, except when displaying them - and then, only in the *local* time zone.

Comment: i choose 4 utc dates only for the example and for the use of 4 dates,so he can do the same with other time zones, i edit my answer because i see its not obivous for some of the people.

Comment: @Oriel.F— `new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00")` will be parsed as local, so the host time zone offset will be applied when creating the date instance. It will result in a different UTC time value for each host with a different time zone offset. Whether `new Date("Wed Mar 25 2015 09:56:24 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)")` is correctly parsed or not is implementation dependent.

Comment: Sorry, but only the offset will be recognized, and Tokyo is certainly not GMT+1.